# Finding current and initial voltages of Inductor, capacitor and resistor

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, electricity

The switch in the following circuit was in position 'a' for long time , before passing to position b at t=0.

Find the initial current.

Find the initial Voltages of the capacitor , the inductor and the resistors.

[image]

**What i tried**

At t=0- , the circuit will look like this :

[image]

Since the switch was closed for a longtime , the current going through the capacitor will become 0 , while the voltage of the inductor will become 0.

Applying KVL : 28 +14I +20=0 , Hence I = -3A = I0

The voltage through the capacitor will be equal to the voltage through the 4K resistor + 28v

vc(t=0) = 4(-(-3))-28=-16V

and finally VL(t=0) = 0 since the inductor is short circuited.

However when the switch passes to the position b , the KVL equation doesn't apply anymore: -16+8(-3)+0+20 is different than zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Misunderstood At t=0 the switch is sort of both open and closed. This is a fictional switch that models the unit step function \$u(t)\$ which has a discontinuity at t=0. Sometimes we talk about t=0- as the infinitesimal instant before the switch moves and t=0+ as the infinitesimal instant after the switch moves.

Comment: Since there was no cap current before,  a switch break before make causes no change, thus is not relevant here.

Comment: @Misunderstood We don't really talk about the impedance of the switch **at** t=0. At t=0- the switch has zero impedance to point a and infinite impedance to point b. At t=0+ the switch has infinite impedance to point a and zero impedance to point b. It takes zero time for the switch to move. We really don't care what happens at the infinitesimally small instant when t is exactly zero.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I don't understand what point you are trying to make. Capacitor current and inductor voltage can be discontinuous; they are never relevant at a switching event. Capacitor voltage and inductor current **are** relevant, even if their value is zero.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson sorry, I misunderstood.  I have deleted my comment. PS, I never understand Tony, be careful or he will take you down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Draw the before and after circuits.  Reorganize the layout if that helps you understand it better.  On your second drawing, note the current in the L and the voltage in the C as those will be necessary to find the voltages asked.  The L will (most likely) have a voltage, it's current will take time to change.

Comment: You will have two initial conditions of non-zero energy storage to deal with. Both the capacitor and inductor will have some energy stored when the switch moves to its new position. You must account for both situations: the voltage across the capacitor and also the current through the inductor. Note that the inductor will make up the needed voltage difference so that KVL works out.

Answer (score 1):

No, KVL still holds. In the instant when the switch moves, it is possible that the capacitor current can change and/or the inductor voltage can change. The thing to remember is that the **capacitor voltage** cannot change instantaneously and the **inductor current** cannot change instantanely...these must have the same value at t=0- and t=0+.

Comment: Yes, VL is not 0. The "before" current is I=E/R = 48/16K = 3ma. The "before" voltages across the 4K & 12K resisters are E=I*R = .003*4K=12V & .003*12K=36V. The voltage across the cap is -28+12 = +20-36 = -16V. The "after" resistance of the 12K & 24K is 8K. So the "after" voltage across the resistors is E=I*R = .003*8K=24V. Then 20-VL-24+16=0 so VL = 12V. But not for long. ( 2nd order differential equation ?!)

Comment: This is what confused me I thought that the voltage across the inductor has to be continuous hence if it’s zero before closing the switch , it has to be zero the moment we close it.

Comment: Yes, as Elliot says, C can change I; L can change V; but C cannot change V; L cannot change I; [instantly].

Answer (score 0):

At \$\small t=0\$ the circuit comprises the series connection of: the C, with an initial voltage of \$ \small -16\: V\$ on the top plate relative to the bottom plate; a resistance of \$\small 8\: k\Omega\$; the L with an initial current of \$\small 3\: mA\$ anticlockwise; and the \$\small 20 \:V \$ source.

Let \$\small I \$ be the anticlockwise current flowing from \$\small t=0\$, then derive the 2nd order differential equation in \$\small I\$ and solve, taking the above initial conditions into account.

Comment: The OP just needs the initial conditions, I don't think much more than algebra is required.

Comment: This isn't the whole answer, but it is part of it.  Still need to do some KVL/KCL to find the other voltages (and currents if that is indeed asked).

Comment: @Jaden we shouldn't give complete answers to homework.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson 1st paragraph of answer gives initial current; initial inductor voltage can then be determined, but homework criterion applies so can't give the full answer.

Comment: My point was that your suggestion to derive a differential equation is unnecessary. I didn't want the OP to be confused by that.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson KVL at \$\small t=0 \$: \$\small -16+(8*10^3*3*10^{-3})+L\frac{dI}{dt}=20\$; hence  \$\small L\frac{dI}{dt}=12\:V\$

Comment: OK, fine, but the OP **doesn't care** about \$\frac{dI}{dt}\$. The OP cares **only** about \$i(0+)\$. I wasn't asking you to give a more complete answer, I was pointing out that you were telling the OP to do analysis that **was not necessary** to answer the question as asked.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson At the top of the OP: *Find the initial current. Find the initial Voltages of the capacitor , the inductor and the resistors.* The OP has made a mistake in the KVL - hasn't recognized that there's a back emf at t=0. Ldi/dt explains where the error lies.

Comment: I don't think so. At t=0+ we know the voltage across the capacitor and the current through the inductor because they are the dc values that existed at t=0-. So we have series circuit and the current is through all elements is known. We use Ohm's Law once and KVL once and we're done...one multiplication and some addition and subtraction. No differential equations. No concern about \$\frac{di}{dt}\$.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson So are you saying that the current is constant at t=0?

Comment: Yes. The **inductor** current does not change from t=0- to t=0+, it must be continuous.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson In that case there's zero voltage across the inductor, so KVL is violated!

Comment: No, I didn't say \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ was zero, I said \$i\$ was continuous. At t=0+ you have to use KVL to **find** \$V_L\$ and then you can calculate \$\frac{di}{dt}\$. See @dcromley's comments to my answer.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson if \$ i\$ is constant \$\frac{di}{dt}=0 \$. dcromley's comments say VL = 12 V, that's back emf isn't it? How else can you get a voltage across an inductor?  Anyway I'm done with this; I suggest you do some work on transient analysis of R/L/C circuits.

Comment: "constant" is not the same as "continuous"